# ZPL - Barcode Missing a digit when printed

Tags: label, barcode, zebra-printers, zpl, barcode-printing

I am trying to print a Code 128 barcode on a label using the following the piece of ZPL with a Zebra ZP 450 printer:

```
^BY3^BCN,112,N^FO090,660^FD>;>89102100^FS
```

I'm expecting the barcode to scan as "9102100".  However, when I scan the printed barcode, it reads as "910210" -- cutting off the final digit.

If I change the last digit, it is still cut off.  But if I add more digits onto the end, e.g. "9102100357", the barcode correctly reads as "9102100357".

Why am I "losing" a digit in this particular case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `>;` inside of your `^FD` block is telling the code 128 barcode to go into a subset (subset C in this case) which forces the data in the barcode to be numeric pairs (00 - 99). Any data that is not supplied in numeric pairs is ignored.  If you put a letter in there, it will ignore that pair.  In your case `9102100` has an odd number of numbers, so it ignores the last one. If for example, you add another `0`, it will put all the letters in the barcode.

The `;>` which puts the barcode in Subset C is not the default. Subset B or `:>` is the default which will allow any character to be encoded in the barcode.  So you can replace the `;>` with `:>`, or just remove the `;>` entirely, and it will print out properly.

Check out the `^BC` documentation in the ZPL programming manual for more information about Code 128 subsets and data validation

Comment: You just saved my day.

Comment: This is one of the dumbest features I've ever heard of. Zebra's ZPL Designer spftware seems to use this subset by default.

Answer (score 0):

See pg 92 of the [ZPL Programming Guide](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf#page=92).

This issue may have been fixed in the firmware update, see below:

> Example: This is an example with the mode parameter set to D*:
>
> ```
> ^XA
> ^PON
> ^LH0,0
> ^BY2,2.5,145
> ^FO218,343
> ^BCB,,Y,N,N,D
> ^FD(91)0005886>8(10)0000410549>8(99)05^FS
> ^XZ
> ```
>
> D* — When trying to print the last Application Identifier with an odd number of characters, a problem
>   existed when printing EAN128 bar codes using Mode D. The problem was fixed in firmware version
>   V60.13.0.6."